# CakePHP3: How can I do text searching using full-text indexes

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I used the below code to search using full-text indexes

```
$query = $this->Posts->find()
    ->contain(['Categories' ])
    ->where([
        'MATCH(Posts.title) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)' => $search
]);
```

But I got the below error

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters
```

Please advise

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try rewriting your query as:

```
$query = $this->Posts->find()
    ->contain(['Categories'])
    ->where([
        "MATCH(Posts.title) AGAINST(:search IN BOOLEAN MODE)" 
    ])
    ->bind(':search', $search);
```

Make sure you have the latest CakePHP 3.x version installed, as this was added no so long ago.

The following will work, but be warned it makes your code **vulnerable to SQL injection attacks**:

```
// for educational purposes only. Don't use in production environments
$query = $this->Posts->find() 
    ->contain(['Categories'])
    ->where([
        "MATCH(Posts.title) AGAINST('{$search}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)" 
    ]);
```

Comment: This will work but will not escape special characters in `$search`. Please advise

Comment: @gonzela2006 I've edited the answer. See if it works.

Comment: I'd advise to remove the first example, as it's a classic SQL injection vulnerability, and people might blindy copy & paste use it without reading the comments.

Comment: @ndm I've reworded the answer without deleting the code. Let me have your thoughts.

Comment: @InigoFlores Thank you very much. It is working like a charm!