# Cakephp 3 Fulltext Search

Tags: cakephp, full-text-search, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to make a FULLTEXT search in Cakephp 3, but there is no native implementation.

I can use `->conditions(["MATCH(Ads.title, Ads.text) AGAINST('$search')"])` but this is going to be vulnerable to injections because there is no sanitization function since Cakephp 3 that I can use.

What am I supposed to do ?

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358366/cakephp3-how-can-i-do-text-searching-using-full-text-indexes/34358821#34358821

Answer (score 5):

You can do it this way:

```
->where(["MATCH(Ads.title, Ads.text) AGAINST(:search)"])
->bind(":search", $search);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
array("MATCH(Ads.title) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)" => $search)
```